# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "testCaseName" (class io.qameta.allure.model.TestResult)

Tags: allure

We recently upgraded Allure (2.27.0) and Allure Jenkins plugin (2.31.1) to the latest versions. Now the Allure report is empty and the log file contains:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "testCaseName" (class io.qameta.allure.model.TestResult), not marked as ignorable (18 known properties: "start", "descriptionHtml", "parameters", "name", "historyId", "statusDetails", "status", "links", "fullName", "uuid", "description", "testCaseId", "stage", "labels", "stop", "steps", "rerunOf", "attachments"\])
```

The build.gradle is:

```
plugins {
id "io.qameta.allure" version "2.11.2"
}
allure {
version = "2.27.0"
adapter {
allureJavaVersion = "2.27.0"
aspectjVersion.set("1.9.22")
autoconfigureListeners.set(true)
aspectjWeaver.set(true)
frameworks {
junit5 {
// Defaults to allureJavaVersion
adapterVersion = "2.26.0"
enabled = true
}
}
}
report {
reportDir.set(project.reporting.baseDirectory.dir("allure-report"))
def resultsDir = "project.reporting.baseDirectory.dir("allure-results")"
}
}
```

Tried upgrading jackson library to the latest version but didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

Also faced that. Downgrading allure version down to 2.16.0 was the solution

Comment: What version of allure-gradle plugin did you use with allure 2.16.0?